# bind arguments to function javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, bind

i'm trying to run second query when first was resolved like so:

```
const fn1 = secondQuery => $.get('1.json', data => secondQuery());
const fn2 = secondQuery => $.get('2.json', data => secondQuery());
const fn3 = secondQuery => $.get('3.json', data => secondQuery());
const fn4 = secondQuery => $.get('4.json', data => secondQuery());

const queries = [fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4];

const queriesWithArgs = queries.map((queryFn, index, arr) => {
    const nextQuery = arr[index + 1];

    if (!nextQuery) {
        return
    }

    return queryFn.bind(queryFn, nextQuery);
});

queriesWithArgs[0]();
```

but still getting error  TypeError: secondQuery is not a function, while requests to 1.json and 2.json works fine fn2 seems to not receive fn3 as argument.
Can you explain how it works ?

Comment: What is `queryFn.bind(queryFn, nextQuery);` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Ah, I guess you meant `queryFn.bind(null, nextQuery);` or simply `() => queryfn(nextQuery)`?

Comment: ^^ `null` would make more sense as the first argument to `bind` there.

Comment: yes @Bergi you right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to think that the `arr` argument refers to the `queriesWithArgs` array, so that you can take your `nextQuery` from there. It doesn't, it refers to the original `queries` array and you are calling those `nextQuery` functions without a further argument.

Instead, the proper tool to use here is [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight), not `map`, where `nextQuery` accumulator will indeed refer to the previous result (or the initial value, here the `last` callback):

```
const queries = [fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4];

const run = queries.reduceRight((nextQuery, queryFn) => {
    return queryFn.bind(null, nextQuery);
}, function last() {
    console.log("done");
});

run();
```

Comment: This must be the first time I've seen a `reduceRight` being used actually for purpose here. Just an odd observation, I suppose.

Comment: The callback version of the classic promise `reduce` trick. :-)

Comment: In fact, assuming this `$.get` is jQuery as seems likely, you could use the promise `reduce` trick for something a bit more idiomatic (to my mind).

Comment: oh got it, thanks.

it's just a synthetic training task, so my purpose was dynamically create somehtnig like fn1.bind(fn2.bind(fn3.bind(fn4))) and then call fn1()

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛитвиненко That `run = fn1.bind(null, fn2.bind(null, fn3.bind(null, fn4.bind(null, last))))` is exactly what `reduceRight` is doing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Tbh I like the `reduceRight` version better, since it allows for faster termination in case of errors. With promises: `queries.reduceRight((inner, queryFn) => prev => queryFn().then(inner), last => {})().then(done)`